# Play music in background using Pyaudio

Tags: python

I am trying to get a song to play in the background and have the game script continue (not have to wait for the song to end to continue).

I have searched and tried to use Pyaudio in callback mode per another post but everytime my audio starts, the rest of my script stops.

```
 print("Hi")
v_player1=input("Player 1, what is your name?\n")
print("Cool, welcome "+v_player1\n)
v_player2=input("Player 2, what is your name?\n")
print("Awesome, hi "+v_player2\n)

v_player1_pkmn=input(v_player1+" pick your pokemon"\n)
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(v_player1_pkmn+'.jpg')
im.show()

v_player2_pkmn=input(v_player2+" pick your pokemon"\n)
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(v_player2_pkmn+'.jpg')
im.show()

v_player1_hp=100
v_player2_hp=100

print("Ready to Battle?!")

    import pyaudio
    import wave


    CHUNK = 1024


    wf = wave.open( 'battle.wav', 'rb')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()



def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
    data= wf.readframes(frame_count)


        while (v_player1_hp > 0 and v_player2_hp > 0):
            v_player1_move = input(v_player1 + ",Select your move:(A)ttack (D)efend (P)otion")

            if v_player1_move.upper() == "A":
                v_player2_hp -= 10
            elif v_player1_move.upper() == "D":
                v_player1_hp == 100
            elif v_player1_move.upper() == "P":
                v_player1_hp += 5
            else:
                print("not a valid move")

            v_player2_move = input(v_player2 + ",Select your move:(A)ttack (D)efend (P)otion")

            if v_player2_move.upper() == "A":
                v_player1_hp -= 10
            elif v_player2_move.upper() == "D":
                v_player2_hp == 100
            elif v_player2_move.upper() == "P":
                v_player2_hp += 5
            else:
                print("not a valid move")

            print("Player1HP " + str(v_player1_hp))
            print("Player2HP " + str(v_player2_hp))

        else:
            if (v_player1_hp > v_player2_hp):
                print(v_player1 + " wins!")
            else:
                print(v_player2 + " wins!")

        return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
wf.close()

p.terminate()
```

Comment: look at threading and multiprocessing things.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you can play wave files asynchronously with `import winsound; winsound.PlaySound(filename, winsound.SND_ASYNC)`.

Comment: The winsound solution did just what I needed. I'll look into threading and multiprocessing as well. Thanks for the help!